# Visa Interview Question has me stomped for a while

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have been trying to resolve this interview question but so far I have not been able to. Please help.

**Question**

There are factories in an area which produce a pollutive gas and filters are to be installed at each factory to reduce pollution.

Each filter installed would half the pollution in that factory. Each factory can have multiple filters.
There is a list of N integers representing the level of pollution in each of the N factories in the area.

Find the minimum number of filters needed to half the overall pollution.

E.g. - Let [3, 5, 6, 1, 18] be the list of pollution levels in 5 factories.
Overall pollution = 3+5+6+1+18 = 33 (target is 33/2 = 16.5)

Install a filter in factory given by index=4 -- > pollution levels will be [3, 5, 6, 1, 9] --> 24
Install a filter in factory given by index=4 -- > pollution levels will be [3, 5, 6, 1, 4.5] --> 19.5
Install a filter in factory given by index=2 -- > pollution levels will be [3, 5, 3, 1, 4.5] --> 16.5

Need 3 filters minimum to half the overall pollution.

N is an integer within the range [1....30,000]. Each element in the list is an integer within the range [0....70,000]

I am not being lazy, here's my incorrect attempt:

```
public static int getMinimumFilters(double[] pollutionLevels) {
    double totalPollution = Arrays.stream(pollutionLevels).sum();
    double targetPollution = totalPollution / 2.0;
    int numFilters = 0;
    double currentPollution = 0;
    double tempPollution = 0;

    Arrays.sort(pollutionLevels);

    for (double i = pollutionLevels.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        currentPollution = (totalPollution - pollutionLevels[(int) i]) + pollutionLevels[(int) i]/2;
        numFilters++;
        if (currentPollution <= targetPollution) {
            break;
        }

    }

    return numFilters;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] pollutionLevels = {3, 5, 6, 1, 18};
    System.out.println("Minimum number of filters needed: " + getMinimumFilters(pollutionLevels));
}
```

My next line of thought was to sum the array and then use the difference between the sum and the targetPollution value to somehow check which array values should be halved to achieve the target.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic `heap` problem where you need to keep the elements sorted while insertion and deletion, in this case we remove max pollution from heap and insert half it's value and pull the next max value right from top of the heap, we could use `PriorityQueue` in java

```
public static int getMinimumFilters(double[] pollutionLevels) {
    double currentPollution = Arrays.stream(pollutionLevels).sum();
    double targetPollution = currentPollution / 2.0;
    PriorityQueue<Double> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(10, Collections.reverseOrder());
    for(double level : pollutionLevels) {
        queue.offer(level);
    }
    int numFilters = 0;
    while(currentPollution > targetPollution) {
        double maxPollution = queue.poll(); 
        double pollutionAfterFilter = maxPollution/2.0;
        queue.offer(pollutionAfterFilter); 
        currentPollution -= pollutionAfterFilter;
        numFilters++;
    }
    return numFilters;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] pollutionLevels = {3, 5, 6, 1, 18};
    System.out.println("Minimum number of filters needed: " + getMinimumFilters(pollutionLevels));
}
```

Comment: In the above solution, I expected to see the queue elements returned in descending order. 

```PriorityQueue<Double> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(10, Collections.reverseOrder());

        for(double level : pollutionLevels) {
            queue.add(level);
        }
  
System.out.println("Descending: "+queue);```


Input: double[] pollutionLevels = {3, 5, 6, 1, 18};

But they don't they are returned as such:

Descending: [18.0, 6.0, 5.0, 1.0, 3.0]

Why is the ordering for 1.0 and 3.0 out of step with descending order?

Comment: Is it better?

Should the implementation of the PriorityQueue be implemented as:

```Queue<Double> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());```

Instead of using the implementation type (PriorityQueue), use the interface type (Queue), giving greater flexibility to change implementations by merely changing the constructor.

Comment: Ideally if the use case demands it, then yes you could simply use `Queue` as type of variable and change it's implementation later as needed! but for above use case it should be ok to just use `PriorityQueue`!